# layout weight not working CardView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-cardview

I want my screen to show a total of 3 cards distributed evenly taking up the whole space but nothing I try seems to be working. The cards are being loaded with the use of a RecyclerView/viewHolder.
I've tried two solutions.

Solution 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_disciplines"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3"
    >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/disciplineName"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
</LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and Solution 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_disciplines"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/disciplineName"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
</LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't see three cards in your solutions? do you want to divide your CardView into 3 equally spaced parts?

Comment: No, the cards load with the use of a viewholder. Sorry, I'm fairly new but I assumed that if I set the layoutweight to 1, when loaded, each card would take an even amount of space on the screen.

Comment: GridView would make your life so easy in that case. Consider changing to GridView. This can be done in RecyclerView too, but just saying.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I want my cards to be full screen width and positioned vertically. Gridview won't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weight_sum="3"
    android:padding="16dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#000">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:text="Card 1"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:background="#000">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:text="Card 2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#000">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:text="Card 3"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I am using a viewholder to load the information I need. If I do it your way, would this work?

Comment: A view holder? is this going to be inside a RecyclerView? If it's you should think about your design, because it'll be really heavy if your adapter is going to have, lets say 100 items on it

Comment: Yes it's inside a recyclerview, I did it this way because it will always return 3 items. I'm using a cardView for styling purposes but instead of the cards distributing evenly, it leaves half the screen empty (i hope i explained that well enough)

Comment: If you're using a recycler view, your layout file should have just one card. RecyclerVIew will create the other ones for you. If you needta bind stuff my solution works fine, as long as you specify ids for each view. If you're always going to return three views, I guess there's no need for a recyclerview, you better just define a layout, bind views and populate it. RecyclerView is a better aproach only when you don't know exactly how many items are gonna be displayed OR when there's too much items to create a layout manually. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, it completely messed up my code :/ Do you have any other suggestions? I'd really appreciate it

Comment: It has printed 3 large cards where each card fits the screen, to see the rest I have to scroll down, I have no idea why that has happened and I did what you suggested, three cardviews within a linear layout.

Comment: updated my answer once again with a result window. Go ahead and try it out

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work as you expected:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#888888"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#000088"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp">


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#008800"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#880000"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
CardView cardView1 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView1);
        CardView cardView2 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView2);
        CardView cardView3 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView3);

        cardView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CardView1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        cardView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CardView2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        cardView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CardView3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I gave this a try but the OnClickListener wont work for each of the cardviews separately

Comment: @SanVed I have updated the above code. Just set id for cardviews and handled onClickListener thats all. I have tested now, It is working good for me.

Comment: @SanVed Please try again

Comment: That did sort out well. I know where I went wrong. I forgot to add the ViewGroup in the Listener.